# Problems with displaying data in html with angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, json

The column im having problems is "Alerta", i checked the log and in getting all the data but is displaying only "Sin Informacion".

this is how i get my JSON array data:

```
 $http.get("conector.php?tipoDato=query3")
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.mensajeEspera = "";
            $scope.datos3 = response.data;

        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.datos3.length; i++){
            var currentObj = $scope.datos3[i];
            currentObj.alertaObject = currentObj.alerta.split(';');
            for (var j in currentObj.alertaObject) {
                currentObj.alertaObject[j] = currentObj.alertaObject[j].replace(/\n/g,'').replace(/\r/g,'');
            }
            $scope.datosAlerta = currentObj.alertaObject;
            console.log(currentObj.alertaObject);
        }
        $scope.datosAlerta = currentObj.alertaObject;
        });
```

I have in the query a filter for null fields in my php query  `coalesce(nullif(project_alert,''),'Sin Informacion') As alerta`

I get the data in the HTML page like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="z in datos3 ">
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"><a  href="#" ng-click="mostrar_proyecto(z.project_id)">{{z.proyecto}}</a></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.complejidad}}</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.glosa}}</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.inicio}}</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.termino}}</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.completado}}</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.estado}}</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.responsable}}</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"> 
        <div class="hooveralerta">
            <div ng-repeat="d in z.datosAlerta">
                {{d}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: If you just run the API call you get the expected response  ? look at the json structure, maybe you didn't access to object correctly

Comment: You're assigning `datosAlerta` in the scope, not in the elements of `dato3`. I guess `currentObj.datosAlerta = currentObj.alertaObject` should do it

Comment: you are correct Lucas, thanks a lot dude